# How to get workemail address of a user using powershell Sharepoint online 365

Tags: powershell, office-365

How to get work email address of a user using powershell in office 365?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Office 365/SharePoint Online, the user's account is their email address, so it is something you need to know if you are doing some sort of command.

Otherwise, you'd have to do a [Get-SPOUser](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp161389.aspx).

```
$users = get-spouser -site "https://tenant.sharepoint.com/teams/eric"
foreach($user in $users){
    //should return email address
    $user.LoginName
    //if no, try this
    $user.LoginName.Split("|")[2]
}
```

Comment: the email address is appended with i:0#.f|membership, how to get it without this

Comment: added an alternative output format

Answer (score 2):

Try this for Office 365

```
Get-MsolUser  | Select-Object UserPrincipalName, DisplayName
```

Where `UserPrincipalName` shows email user

To export the result

```
Get-MsolUser  | Select-Object UserPrincipalName, DisplayName | Export-Csv c:\Users.csv
```